# ktor - Csrf token handling

Tags: ktor, csrf-token

I'm very new to ktor, and want to use it as a client to my spring-boot CSRF protected REST service from my Android phone.

I just don't get how I'm supposed to do that with ktor version 1.4.0.  I read about Pipelines, which seems to be what I need, but I don't find anything related to CSRF, and frankly, there must be something there, right?  Or do I have to write this myself???

Any pointers highly appreciated,
Henning

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Ktor has no built-in support for CSRF protection.